# Assign results of dynamic sql into a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables, dynamic

What I want to do is to get the “value result” of the query in a variable @statement.

the code looks as follows:

```
declare @ID int, @name varchar (200), @statement varchar (200)

set @ID = 25
set @name = 'select FirstName + '' '' + LastName as ''Full Name''
             from person.person  
             where BusinessEntityID = ' + cast (@ID as varchar)'
set @statement = 'My name is @name'
```

I'd like to show the results from @statement, and I know i should use sp_executesql to execute my @name query, and output it @statement, but I am not sure how to do that.

Any thoughts and thanks!

Answer (score 3):

A little confused.  No need for the dynamic SQL

**Example**

```
declare @ID int, @name varchar (200)
set @id=25

set @name = 'My name is ' + (select FirstName + ' ' + LastName 
                               from person.person  
                               where BusinessEntityID = @ID
                             )
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like the output to be a statement as 'My name is xxxx', that's why I am considering the 3rd variable @statement...

Comment: @Kay Updated  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `concat()` :

```
select top (1) @name = concat('My name is ', FirstName, ' ', LastName)
from person.person  
where BusinessEntityID = @ID;
```

I would use to `top (1)` if BusinessEntityID matching pair has multi row.